# How to export SAS dataset to a .dat

Tags: sas

I have a  [SAS dataset `chapter5.pressure`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/pressure.sas7bdat) and i verified that it is fine by printing it `proc print`:

```
                               Obs    SBPbefore    SBPafter

                                 1       120          128
                                 2       124          131
                                 3       130          131
                                 4       118          127
                                 5       140          132
                                 6       128          125
                                 7       140          141
                                 8       135          137
                                 9       126          118
                                10       130          132
                                11       126          129
                                12       127          135
```

So, I want to export it to the `.dat` file, and the following method does not work:

```
libname chapter5 'c:\users\owner\desktop\sas\chapter5';

data _null_;
set chapter5.pressure;
file 'c:\users\owner\desktop\sas\chapter5\xxx.dat';
put a b ;
run;
```

The resulting [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/xxx.dat) has all missing values. Why

Comment: What format do you want your .dat file to be in?  Is it a fixed width file, a delimited file (comma, space, tab, etc.), or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the variable names instead of "a" and "b".

```
data _null_;
set chapter5.pressure;
file 'c:\users\owner\desktop\sas\chapter5\xxx.dat';
put SBPbefore SBPafter;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a `put` statement, you can also use `PROC EXPORT` to create a delimited file from a SAS dataset:

```
PROC EXPORT 
     DATA=chapter5.pressure
     OUTFILE='c:\users\owner\desktop\sas\chapter5\xxx.dat' 
     DBMS=DLM
     REPLACE;
RUN;
```

The default delimiter is a blank, which should match what you are trying to do.  To create a tab or comma-delimited file, change the DBMS option value to `TAB` or `CSV` respectively.  This will create a header row in the external file. [Here is a link to the SAS 9.2 documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000316288.htm). Check the SAS support site if you are using a different version.